# How can I implement an input element, but also with select options in HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css, select, input

[example of needed input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EyOt.png) I need an input field, which will also open some options when clicked. If I choose from options, the input text has to stay.
For example, you can choose an email domain from options, but type your own email. Please help!

I tried to just merge input and select by removing padding, but I want to be able to click anywhere including input field to open options.

Is it possible to do in pure HTML/CSS or mby some ReactJS

Comment: That doesn't look like a native `<select>` to me.  It looks like perhaps a custom floating `<div>` (or other such element) which is dynamically updated by code when the `<input>` value changes.  There are *many* existing tools/plugins you can use for this, or potentially write your own.  But simply "merging and input and select" and re-styling them certainly won't accomplish that.  If, as you imply, you are perhaps using ReactJS then you might take a look at the MUI library which has many such components.

Answer (score 1):

I think on pure HTML/CSS it will be hard, solution on react:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const EmailInput = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
  const [showOptions, setShowOptions] = useState(false);
  
  const emailDomains = ['gmail.com', 'yahoo.com', 'outlook.com', 'custom'];

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleOptionClick = (domain) => {
    if (domain === 'custom') {
      // If 'custom' is selected, keep the input value without changing it
      setShowOptions(false);
    } else {
      // If a predefined domain is selected, append it to the input value
      setInputValue(`${inputValue}@${domain}`);
      setShowOptions(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="email-input-container">
      <input
        type="text"
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        onFocus={() => setShowOptions(true)}
        placeholder="Enter your email"
      />

      {showOptions && (
        <div className="email-options">
          {emailDomains.map((domain) => (
            <div key={domain} onClick={() => handleOptionClick(domain)}>
              {domain}
            </div>
          ))}
          <div onClick={() => handleOptionClick('custom')}>Custom</div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default EmailInput;
```